# Do I need to download the Forge Mod Loader to have a mods folder in my .minecraft folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

So, do I need the Forge Mod Loader or can I just slap a mods folder in there and call it a day?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to install Forge or Fabric (an option in newer versions of Minecraft) as those are the frameworks for mods which incidentally handles "loading" them.

Minecraft in it's vanilla form doesn't do anything with the mods folder and obviously nothing happens.

If you're struggling to install mods manually, you are better off using user-friendly clients like CurseForge (supercedes FTB), MultiMC or Technic

Comment: I got it running but I have a question. Does the Cubic Chunks mod make any use of the Biome Scale Weight value? If not what would be it's equivalent? I'm trying to give a 1.12.2 world the Caves & Cliffs height/ depth limit and trigger the Monolith Glitch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CjW4pPwtaQ